# button for download a file

Tags: flutter

I've done this code in flutter web

```
 ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    downloadFile("/Users/aaa/Desktop/a.pdf");
                  },
                  child: Text('Platform-specific Button'),
                ): Text('Button not supported on web')
                ],

...

downloadFile(url){
  AnchorElement anchorElement = new AnchorElement()
  anchorElement.download = "jjjjjj.pdf";
  anchorElement.click();
}
```

for a button that when is clicked download a file from the file system.

The problem is that the file jjjjjj.pdf that I get is in HTML code and not in PDF as I expect.

Comment: Surely it would be a massive security hole if a web application could read arbitrary files from the file system!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this packages that might help you solve the problem.
This is how I make a pdf available for download.
You probably want to skip the screenshot part.

```
import 'package:open_filex/open_filex.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

...

// the onPressed event you call

Future<void> saveScreenShotAsPdf(BuildContext context, Uint8List 
    screenshotBytes) async {

    final pdf = pw.Document();
    pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (pw.Context context) {
            return pw.Center(
                child: pw.Image(
                       pw.MemoryImage(screenshotBytes),
                       fit: pw.BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                );
            },
        ),
    );

    final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = '${directory.path}/your_file.pdf';
    final File file = File(path);
    await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
    await OpenFilex.open(file.path);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: ```AnchorElement``` is not suitable for downloading files, especially when the file is not a web resource.